# Laravel Model function using relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I made this function in my view for summing total hours

```
<?php 

     $sum = [];
     foreach($user->workedTimes as $item){
        array_push($sum, ($item->end_time->diffInHours($item->start_time))); 
     }
     echo array_sum($sum);

?>
```

And in blade view all is fine, but i want that same code in my Model so i can call user->totalHours in blade

and i made this function in my Model:

[image]

and when i call {{ $user->totalHours }}

i get this error:

[image]

How to make this work from Model??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the method with brackets like this:

```
{{ $user->totalHours() }}
```

But it would be good if you use [Laravel Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function getTotalTimeAttribute()
    {
       // Your logic here ...
       $sum = [];
       foreach($this->workedTimes as $item) {
         array_push($sum, $item->end_time->diffInHours($item->start_time));
       }
       return array_sum($sum);
    }
}
```

and access it in blade like this:

```
{{ $user->total_time }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: cool this works!!! but i have another problem now......i get the output like this `19 {{-- 19--}} ` instead of `19` where do this extra brackets and another value come?????

Comment: oh man i got commented my php code with this {{-- --}} but it was actually not commented......all is fine now....thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$this->workedHours()` and call it with `$user->totalHours()`